# Using DOS batch script: find a line in a properties file and replace text

Tags: string, batch-file, replace, dos

Trying to replace a string in a properties file on a certain line by using a batch file.  I know that this can be done WITHOUT the use of a temp file, as I have seen it before, but forgotten how to do it.

I know that if I have a var.properties file that contains this:

```
CLASSPATH=bsh.jar;other.jar
VARTEST=dummy
ANOTHERVAR=default
```

I am trying to update the CLASSPATH value in the .properties file without changing the order of the properties file.

This is a properties file and so I believe the answer would be related to using:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims==" %%i in (var.properties) do (
  @echo Key=%%i Val=%%j
)
```

Comment: From what I understand you want to read and then write (selectively) into the var.properties file. I can't think of a way where you could get this done without creating another file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally broke down and accepted a method using a "temp" file.  Using delayed expansion with the '!' character solved my question.   Much of this success was due to input by [mecaflash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/781339/mechaflash) .

You can call this script with: *CALL Script.bat PropKey NewPropValue Filename*

```
@echo off
:: script for updating property files
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
if "%3"=="" (
  ECHO Script will optionally accept 3 args: PropKey PropVal File
  SET PROPKEY=UseCompression
  SET PROPVAL=false
  SET FILE=config.properties
) ELSE (
  SET PROPKEY=%1
  SET PROPVAL=%2
  SET FILE=%3
)
FINDSTR /B %PROPKEY% %FILE% >nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 GOTO nowork
MOVE /Y "%FILE%" "%FILE%.bak"
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%A IN (`TYPE "%FILE%.bak" ^|FIND /N /I "%PROPKEY%"`) DO (
  SET LINE=%%A
)
FOR /F "tokens=1,2* delims=]" %%S in ("%LINE%") DO SET LINE=%%S
SET /A LINE=%LINE:~1,6%
SET /A COUNT=1
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%A IN (`FIND /V "" ^<"%FILE%.bak"`) DO (
  IF "!COUNT!" NEQ "%LINE%" (
      ECHO %%A>>"%FILE%"
  ) ELSE (
      ECHO %PROPKEY%=%PROPVAL%>>"%FILE%"
      ECHO Updated %FILE% with value %PROPKEY%=%PROPVAL%
  )
  SET /A COUNT+=1
)
GOTO end
:nowork
echo Didn't find matching string %PROPKEY% in %FILE%. No work to do.
pause
:end
```

Comment: This script works fine but I found one problem. It is removing all the blank lines from the file. Any idea on how to keep blank lines intact?

Comment: Yes, there is a way but its weird.  I think you will find the secret in here (if I remember correctly):  https://gist.github.com/djangofan/9137336

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `findstr` use `find` with the `/v` and `/i` switches on "classpath".  This will OMIT returning the line with classpath in it, then you can echo what you want in the file along w/`VARTEST=dummy`

```
SET NEWVAL=CLASSPATH=test.jar
SET FILE=think.properties
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%A IN (`TYPE "%FILE%" ^|FIND /V /I "classpath"`) DO (
 ECHO CLASSPATH=%NEWVAL%>>"%FILE%"
 ECHO %%A>>"%FILE%"
)
```

EDIT:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET NEWVAL=test.jar
SET OLDFILE=OLD_think.properties
SET NEWFILE=think.properties
SET COUNT=1

MOVE "%NEWFILE%" "%OLDFILE%"

FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%A IN (`TYPE "%OLDFILE%" ^|FIND /C /I "classpath"`) DO (
 SET LINE=%%A
 )
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%A IN (`FIND /V "" ^<"%OLDFILE%"`) DO (
 IF %COUNT% NEQ %LINE% (ECHO %%A>>"%NEWFILE%") ELSE (ECHO %NEWVAL%>>"%NEWFILE%")
 SET /a COUNT=!COUNT!+1
)
```

Basically states,

1. rename think.properties to OLD_think.properties
2. read OLD_think.properties and find the line number with string
   "classpath" in it and set it to variable LINE
3. Find all lines in OLD_think.properties, and echo them into think.properties. once you reach the line where your "CLASSPATH" string existed, it inserts the new line you wanted to replace it with, and everything else stays the same.

Comment: I see. Then I am unsure on what you can do. Batch/DOS scripting is crap when it comes to editing characters/strings in a file, especially when you need to be specific to a character or line. I know they have resource kits for linux based CLI file editing (like awk). But not sure if this is what you are willing to do.

Comment: If only there were special end of line characters, there may be a possible way of doing this.

Comment: oh snaps... my mistake gave me a stroke of genious... editing my post wait a minute =D

Comment: made an additional edit. Forgot to replace 3 with %LINE% in the IF statement

Comment: I finally figured it out.  See my answer to this question.