# win cmd: batch string replacement deletes "!"

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, cmd, str-replace

I have stitched, w/o any deeper cmd knowledge, a script that searches for certain string in specified files in a directory and replaces it with another. (at least should)

Goes like

```
  set "search=readed"
  set "replace=read"
  set "myfiles=.\*.tex"

for %%f in (%myfiles%) do (
  set /p val=<%%f
  echo "fullname: %%f"


  for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type %%f ^& break ^> %%f ') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >>%%f echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!)
        endlocal


  )
)
pause
```

Almost works. It has two issues.
1st - the less important: deletes whitespace lines.
2nd - deletes exclamations.
before:

```
% !TEX root = TechRep.tex
```

after:

```
% TEX root = TechRep.tex
```

May I ask for a help? Thanks!

Comment: Remove the closing parenthesis at the end of your `echo` command. Despite its looks, it does *not* match the opening parenthesis on the same line! Instead, it matches the opening parenthesis after the `do` keyword.

Comment: That seems to work fine. Thank you!

Comment: If you are editing a file with pure batch for the thrill of it (for the challenge), then knock yourself out. But if you simply want to accomplish a task, then I strongly recommend something else. Pure batch is terrible for text file editing because it is slow, and robust solutions require arcane, non-intuitive syntax and techniques. I recommend [JREPL.BAT - a hybrid regular expression text processing utility that uses JScript and batch](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044): `for %%F in (*.tex) do call jrepl "readed" "read" /f "%%F" /o -`

Comment: Hi! It doesnt bring me any special joy. I just need the stuff to work regardless the machine and its config. Using what I almost know.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems:

1. Skipped blank lines. This is caused by a restriction in the `for /f` command. You can use the old [findstr trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21934313/638028) to get around that.
2. Removed exclamation marks. This is caused by an errant closing parenthesis `)` in your `echo` command. The opening parenthesis in `echo(` on the same line is ignored, and is not matched with the closing parenthesis. Instead, the closing parenthesis is matched with the start of the `do` loop. The next line, containing the `endlocal` command, is *outside* the loop. This seems to cause problems as there is a setlocal inside a loop and an endlocal outside; by some strange mechanism, this somehow causes the exclamation marks to be removed. Remove the `)` from the echo line and this problem disappears.

Comment: No, you can't change `echo(` to `echo ` because the script will then write `ECHO is off.` if it encounters a line that consists of nothing but spaces.

Comment: Exclamation points from line 2 and onward are removed because delayed expansion is enabled, and `%%I` will expand expressions with exclamation points (delayed expansion occurs after FOR variable expansion).

Comment: Ill probably survive the blanks removal. The bracket ending cleared. ;)

Comment: @dbenham good point. I've removed the incorrect statement from my answer.